# Jquery Ajax & Google Maps v3 API Markers - a { or (

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery, google-maps-api-3, kml

Hi I have the following function that I am trying to create based on a google example which did not use the ajax method. I'm having a problem with my }'s or )'s I think and I could do with some one just having a look at where I am going wrong as I've been at this for some time now.

The line marked below is been flagged as having a syntax problem although I can not work out what.

Many Thanks all.

Terran

```
      // http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html
      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file

     function showGetResultkml()
{
     var result = null;
     var scriptUrl = "http://www.kml";
     $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
                                                });

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }    
// problem with this bracket      
});
// problem with this bracket      
}

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
        } 
     });
     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
// http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file

function showGetResultkml()
{
    var result = null;
    var scriptUrl = "http://www.kml";
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            result = data;
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

                var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        }                          
    });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html)
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
        {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Just looking briefly and i cant see off hand what has changed?